# How can I cast an Image object to a File object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, casting

I am attempting to cast an Image to a File in Flutter. Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how to pick an image as a file

```
File _image;

Future getImage() async {
     final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     setState(() {
       _image = File(pickedFile.path);

     });
   }
```

Also We can convert this image as Bytestream

```
var convertedImage;

Future getImage() async {
     final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
     convertedImage = await pickedFile.readAsBytes();
     convertedImage = await decodeImageFromList(convertedImage);
     setState(() {
       convertedImage = convertedImage;
     });
   }
```

Hope this helps!